# How do you disable a virtual directory under IIS?

Tags: iis, virtual-directory

I need to disable a virtual directory on a server without disabling the rest of the virtual directories and applications running on that box.

In this case, the virtual directory I wish to disable shares a physical directory with an application that needs to stay up.  For this reason, I cannot use the [recommended technique of adding app_offline.htm](https://serverfault.com/questions/46464/iis6-turn-off-or-disable-a-virtual-directory-for-downtime-upgrade).

Is there a flag or a setting within IIS that I can use to stop the virtual directory from using?

Comment: Is it suitable to convert this virtual directory to Application depending on your needs? If so, then exists an elegant solution for disabling specific Application.

Comment: A virtual directory is just a pointer, so you can delete it without deleting the underlying folder. Which is the normal way to "disable" it. If there is some reason you really don't want to delete it, you could revoke permissions on its "Connect as" user, which is defined as part of the vdir's "basic settings" in IIS.

Answer (score 2):

Back up your `applicationhost.config` file located in c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config

Then just right click on the virtual directory you want to remove and click remove.

When you want to restore it, just overwrite the applicationhost.config file with the backup you took.

Comment: I opened applicationhost.config and remove the virtual directories

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be to :

- Create a new application pool similar to existing pool i.e. using same .NET CLR 
  version and pipeline mode.
- Then set the virtual directory's application pool to newly created app pool.
- Finally, stop the application pool hosting your virtual directory.

For more information refer this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753449(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: Virtual directories does not have application pools. Your answer works fine for disabling a web application but not a virtual directory.